# Push javascript to console.log new opened page by link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to push my javascript code to new opened page (preferred to console.log)

Here is my function:

```
(function () {
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            window.location.href = "http://mylink";
        }, 1000)
    };
});
```

and I need to run it in new page:

```
<a href="javascript:(function () {
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        setInterval(function () { 
            window.location.href=http://mylink;
        },1000)
    };
});">click</a>
```

Also I tryed to add the code like this? but it doesn't work too:

```
<a href="javascript: console.log('(function (){
        window.onbeforeunload = function () {
            setInterval(function () { 
                window.location.href=http://mylink;
            },1000)
        };
});')">click</a>
```

Could yu help me please

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Redirect the user to a new page when they are trying to exit?

Answer (score 0):

setInterval would not work inside onbeforeunload. It will add event to queue and than simply exit page and never execute.

Edit:
You will see this if you modify code like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        console.log('interval execution');
        window.location.href = "http://mylink";
    }, 1000)
};
```

There will be no output on console log.